# Access Weight and Bias with nn::sequential

Tags: libtorch

If I define `std::vector<torch::nn::Linear> linear_layers;` and fill this vector with some `torch::nn::Linear` objects, then I can access the `weight` and `bias` values by `linear_layers[k].weight` and `linear_layers[k].bias`. Same feature is available with other layer types, e.g., `torch::nn::Conv2d`.

If create my network using `nn::sequential` and then push back either of `Linear` or `Conv2d` I cannot access the `weight` and `bias` directly. Now, my question is how can I access the weight and bias values of each layer when I have used `nn::sequential`?

Thanks,
Afshin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the soultion: [see the link https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/common-class-of-linear-conv-etc/39987/8 ]

## include

using namespace torch;
using namespace torch::nn;

int main()
{
    auto net = Sequential(Conv2d(1 /*input channels*/, 1 /*output channels*/, 2 /*kernel size*/),
                              Conv2d(1, 1, 2));

```
for (auto& p : net->named_parameters()) {

    NoGradGuard no_grad;

    // Access name.
    std::cout << p.key() << std::endl;

    // Access weigth and bias.
    p.value().zero_(); // set all zero
    std::cout << p.value() << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

The layers of a sequential, have the following naming convention: ., e.g. see the console output

```
0.weight # name of the layer
(1,1,.,.) = 
  0  0
  0  0
[ Variable[CPUFloatType]{1,1,2,2} ]
0.bias
 0
[ Variable[CPUFloatType]{1} ]
1.weight
(1,1,.,.) = 
  0  0
  0  0
[ Variable[CPUFloatType]{1,1,2,2} ]
1.bias
 0
[ Variable[CPUFloatType]{1} ]
```